# appshot does not display graph on debian 11

Tags: shiny, webshot

I try to use appshot to take an image from a shiny app.
It works well on Windows, but not on my Debian server.
If I try this:

```
  appdir <- system.file("examples", "01_hello", package = "shiny")
  appshot(appdir, "01_hello.png")
```

this gives this:

[image: webshot_without_graph] (without the graph)

My server is Debian 11.5 with:

- Shiny Server v1.5.18.987
- Node.js v16.14.0
- R version 4.2.1
- phantomjs install like this : https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620.

If anyone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install the 2.1.1 version of phantomjs.

Follow this https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620 but replace 1.9.8 by 2.1.1.

It works !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).